# Asking "Yes" or "No" questions so that I don't use a certain technology

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'll be learning how to use Xamarin from scratch for a mobile device app that runs on iPhone and Android phones. I'm a C# developer, but I know there's a steep learning curve.

I'll be using Xamarin.Forms because it's the most efficient way to create the app for both mobile environments, but I know it has limits.

Can I ask questions with only a *yes* or *no* answer so that I know if certain functionality can be made?

For example, a question would be: can I add pins to a map in Xamarin.Forms and can these pins be seen in an iPhone 7 and a Galaxy S9?

That way, if the answer is a resounding ***NO***, then I won't go through the trouble of learning and using Xamarin.Forms knowing that the end-result is impossible.

Comment: There are better ways to ask yes/no questions. Provide research showing you can't find a definitive answer, and don't ask "is this possible", ask "I need to add a pin to this map, and have tried using [something]. How can I add pins to a map in Xamarin.Forms or other ways"

Comment: There's a steep learning curve to get to the point that I can say _"... and have tried using [something]"_. If the definitve answer is that it can't be done, then all that time and energy to getting to that point was a waste of time.

Comment: Whether to use a certain technology or not is very dependent on multiple factors, none of which make it a good question, and is something that needs to be researched independently.  We can tell you how to use a technology.  We can't tell you if said technology should even be used.  For specific uses, such as your pins example, well, look it up.  That's what research is for.  Asking such a question would rightfully get downvoted for that lack, and for it's minimal utility.

Comment: You're right. My concern was that I didn't want to waste time and energy learning something that will end up not helping me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.  But for cases like that, SO is **not** the place to ask.  Most users are going to very much dislike being treated like a research assistant for someone who wouldn't spend their own time to figure it out.  If you don't want to spend your own time, then the other currency you have is money.  Hire a consultant.

Comment: The answer to _Can X be achieved with programming language/framework Y given infinite time, money and effort_ is almost exclusively yes, as it is in this case. But it's not a sensible question.

Answer (score 2):

No, such kind of questions aren't really helpful.
You have to specify what your showstoppers are when selecting from existing technologies.
Maybe you could gather some directions at SE Software Engineering, but generally such kind of yes / no questions renders too broad.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought whenever I see an "is this possible" question is that the OP simply didn't do any research. They somehow found out about Stack Overflow and though "I bet they'll know."

Now, like fbueckert said, nothing is inherently wrong with that. Of course you'd want to exert as little effort as possible, because that's the most efficient thing to do... for ***you***. You need to remember that potential answerers are also people.

Answering questions here isn't anyone's job (except maybe on Meta when employees respond to questions); it's a volunteer position. Instead of you doing the research, you're now asking *others* to essentially do your work for you. Maybe someone is willing to put in that effort for you, but most people probably aren't.

Then there's the issue of usefulness. The whole reason Stack Exchange even exists is so there's a place with questions and answers that anyone could potentially use for their benefit. A question asking "is this possible" can really only receive an answer that says "yes" or "no." That "yes" might be accompanied by a link to some solution, but since it's not asked for in the question, it might not be provided. Imagine how annoying it would be if you searched

> can I add pins to a map in Xamarin.Forms and can these pins be seen in an iPhone 7 and a Galaxy S9?

in Google, and you found the exact question title on Stack Overflow, with an answer count of 1 or more, only for them all to say

> yes

"Yes" what? How do you do it? It's simply not that helpful to anyone but the person who was asking it before they actually started trying to do it. You might have the motivation to keep researching and eventually figure out a solution, but Stack Overflow is there so you don't necessarily have to do all that.

Then there's the problem that Erik brought up. The answer to "can I do this" is always technically "yes." It might not be feasible, but it is always possible.

---

Instead of asking "can I do this," do what Sterling suggested. Assume it's possible, and then ask how to do it. That makes it better for you—because there's a chance someone knows the solution, or at least knows of a library or other FOSS project that does it—and it makes it better for anyone else who has the same question.